# If $0<x<y$, then prove that $\sqrt{x} <\sqrt{y}$ and $x <\sqrt{xy} <y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, radicals

In terms of Inequalities, we have covered till AM-GM inequality and Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality in class. I was thinking about applying AM-GM inequality but not sure if its right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$0<x<y$.

$(y-x)=$

$(√y-√x)(√y+√x)>0.$

Since $√y+√x >0$,  we get

$√y -√x>0$, or $√y>√x$.

$x=√x√x <√x√y <√y√y =y$

Answer (score 3):

Because $$\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{x}=\frac{y-x}{\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{x}}>0,$$
$$y-\sqrt{xy}=\sqrt{y}(\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{x})>0$$ and
$$\sqrt{xy}-x=\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{x})>0.$$

Comment: if we have a>b and multiply it by z, the inequality sign will remain same only if z>0 so how do we show that 1/(√y + √x) >0 ?

Comment: @RiRi Because $\sqrt{x}>0$ and $\sqrt{y}>0.$

Comment: Ahhh okie! because it's mention that 0<x and 0<y hence  √x and √y exist. Got it now thank you!

Comment: @RiRi You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

$
\sqrt{x} <\sqrt{y}
\implies
x = \sqrt{x} \sqrt{x} < \sqrt{x} \sqrt{y} = \sqrt{xy}
$

$
\sqrt{x} <\sqrt{y}
\implies
\sqrt{xy} = \sqrt{x} \sqrt{y} < \sqrt{y} \sqrt{y} = y
$