# prove that $\sqrt{x+1} \gt \sqrt{x}$ if $x \gt 1$

Tags: inequality

This question is in relation to the specific case where $\sqrt{3} \gt \sqrt{2}$. Can we generalize this result and prove that  $\sqrt{x+1} \gt \sqrt{x}$ if $x \gt 1$. Can we also prove the more general case that $\sqrt{y} \gt \sqrt{x}$ if $0 \lt x \lt y$

Comment: Note that the derivative of $\sqrt(x) $ is positive for all $x > 0$, i.e. $\sqrt(x) $ increases monotonuously

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $0<x<y$, then prove that $\sqrt{x} <\sqrt{y}$ and $x <\sqrt{xy} <y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2961573/if-0xy-then-prove-that-sqrtx-sqrty-and-x-sqrtxy-y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $y>0,x\ge0$

$$\sqrt y-\sqrt x=\dfrac{y-x}{\sqrt y+\sqrt x}$$ will be $>=<0$ according as $y-x>=<0$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ then
$$
f’(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} > 0,
$$
so $f(x)$ is monotonically increasing function (for $x>0$), which is exactly what you need to show.

Answer (score 0):

Squaring both sides we get $$x+1>x$$ or $$1>0$$ which is true.

Answer (score 0):

for non-negative numbers $y,z$ we have $$y<z \iff  y^2<z^2$$ because $f(x)=x^2$ is strictly increasing in the interval $[0,\infty[$. Therefore you can square an inequality without changing the set of solutions, if the values must both be non-negative.

Since the roots are by definition non-negative , you can square always the inequality, if both sides are a root of some expression.