# Is there an elementary proof for the monotonicity of $\sqrt x$?

Tags: inequality, alternative-proof

I am about teaching a course on inequalities to secondary school children and I find we'll have to use at some point that if $$0<a<b,$$ then $$\sqrt a<\sqrt b.$$

Therefore, I've been thinking of how one would go about explaining why this is true to these children, and the only way I know uses real analysis -- and they've definitely taken no calculus yet.

Hence, do you know of a way to prove this result using elementary means?

Thank you.

Comment: If $\sqrt{a}\ge\sqrt{b}$, then $a/ge b$, which is false. So $\sqrt{a}<\sqrt{b}$. Is proof by contradiction too advanced?

Comment: @almagest Hm, I didn't think of this. Thanks -- not at all is it too advanced.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2961573/42969.

Comment: @MartinR Your first link contains the leading answer here, and the proof by contradiction. Your second link as well.  It would have been more useful if they had come earlier. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $0\leq a<b$.

Thus, $$\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{a}=\frac{b-a}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}>0.$$

Comment: Very slick, +1 for you

Comment: Kind of prefer $\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{a}$ in the denominator, but what the heck. (+1)

Answer (score 2):

If $0 \le x \le y$ then $x^2 \le y^2$ since $y^2 - x^2 = (y - x)(y + x) \ge 0$.

Then assume that $\sqrt{b} \le \sqrt{a}$. Then applying above inequality (with $x = \sqrt{b}$ and $y = \sqrt{a}$) we get $b \le a$. This contradicts with $a < b$.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you would mean by elementary. How "elementary" do you want?

Can you use the fact that "$(x- y)(x+ y)= x^2- y^2$" (which can, of course, be shown by just multiplying x- y and x+ y).  Your students would also need to know that "positive times positive is positive", "negative times negative is positive", and "positive times negative is negative".

If 0< a< b, then b- a> 0.  with $x= \sqrt{b}$ and $y= \sqrt{a}$, we can factor $b- a= (\sqrt{b}- \sqrt{a})(\sqrt{b}+ \sqrt{a})> 0$.  Since $\sqrt{a}$ and $\sqrt{b}$ are positive by definition, $\sqrt{a}+ \sqrt{b}$ is positive and it follows that $\sqrt{b}- \sqrt{a}$ is positive so $\sqrt{b}> \sqrt{a}$.

Answer (score 1):

Prove that the the function $f(x) = x^2$ on $[0,+\infty]$ is increasing.

Use some online tools to cut/paste/manipulate its graph and then display

[image]

Mention that using the paint tool eraser you can remove the red below the

'what was the $y\text{-axis}$ but is now the $x\text{-axis}$'.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you've already established that multiplication by a positive quantity preserves inequalities.

If $a < b$ then
$$
aa < ab < bb .
$$

What you want for square roots follows easily.

Comment: I must be missing something. How does $\sqrt a<\sqrt b$ follow from your last set of inequalities?

Comment: @Allawonder Only one of the two orderings of the two square roots leads to the correct inequality on $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow...